# Facebook not getting any Permissions except public profile

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook

I am trying to login with facebook, after login i am trying to get photos permission. However i am just getting public profile. Why its not retrieving user photos permissions?

```
private void registerFacebook()
        {       
            isFetchingFB = false;
            mDialog.show();
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
                {
                    if (session.isOpened())
                    {
                        getUserPhotosPermission(session);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        if (!session.isOpened())
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "!session.isOpened()");
                        else
                            Log.d("FACEBOOK", "isFetching");

                    }
                }
            });     
        }

        private void getUserPhotosPermission(Session session)
        {       
            List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("user_photos");
            final Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, permissions)
            .setRequestCode(ACTIVITY_RESULT_FB);
            session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);       
        }

        private void getUserMeRequest()
        {
            final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            Request getMe = Request.newMeRequest(session, new GraphUserCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                {
                    if (user != null && !isFetchingFB)
                    {
                        isFetchingFB = true;
                        org.json.JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                        String name = graphResponse.optString("name");
                        String id = graphResponse.optString("id");
                        callFacebookApi(name, id, session.getAccessToken());
                    }
                    else
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            getMe.executeAsync();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per new facebook sdk and policy you need to submit your apk and detail explanation to facebook submit and review department for granting extended permission.